# Passing data with completion swift not working

Tags: swift

I want pass date but not called

```
if let recentSortCell = self.recentsCell() {
                let currentPhoto = Helper.shared.groupBy(identifier: photo!.path!)

                if let currentPhoto = currentPhoto {
                        recentSortCell.updateGroupLocalIdentifiers(photoGroup: currentPhoto, complate: { photos in
                            print("success")
                            print(photos.count)
                    })
                }
            }
```

**updateGroupLocalIdentifiers** function complate but not print "success"

```
func updateGroupLocalIdentifiers(photoGroup: Group, complate: @escaping([Itemm]) -> ()) {
        ...
        } else {
            updatePhotoCollectionViewUI(localIdentifiers: LocalIdentifiers, complate: { photos in
                print("complate")
                complate(photos)
            })
        }
    }
```

but printing complate

Comment: What's in the `if` in the ... part of your code. Any chance that there's a `print("complate")` there too and you're never actually hitting your `else`?

Comment: "complate" printing, every time go with else

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your completion handler return an array of Item not a single item.